# Subtraction from the number until it is not equal to zero

Tags: python

I've got a list of numbers [5,10,15,20] and I've got some kind of "discount" value let's say it is 20. The thing I want to do is to substract this discount value from every number until discount is equal to 0 (20-5=15, 15-10=5 then 15-5 = 10). I've tried something like this:

```
for i in list: 
    while i[0] > 0: 
        i[0] - discount 
        if discount != 0: 
            continue 
        else: 
            break
```

But it seems to have no effect at all

Comment: `I` is each number in `list`, so `i[0]` is `5[0]` the first time, then `10[0]`, and so on. That doesn’t make any sense. Even if you just do `i - discount`, that’s `5 - 20`, not `20 - 5`. And then you don’t do anything with that result anyway. What were you expecting that line to do? If you can explain your logic in English, you can then translate that logic to code, but if you don’t know what you’re trying to write, you can’t.

Comment: By "(20-5=15, 15-10=5 then 15-5 = 10)", did you actually mean "(20-5=15, 15-10=5 then 5-5 = 0)"? The latter makes more sense to me, since you're iteratively subtracting elements from the list in reverse order. Otherwise, I don't understand why 15 is the left hand term in two of the steps.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly I do not understand what you have done in your code. Try not to use list as a variable as it is a keyword. If I understand your problem correctly, the following code checks if discount =0 . If it is then it breaks out of loop. If discount is a value greater than 0 then it subtracts the next list item from discount value. I have done discount <= 0 to prevent an infinite value in case discount value becomes negative. There is another problem in your code. You do i[0] where i is an integer value from your list which does not make any sense.

```
for i in my_list:
    if discount<=0:
        break
    else:
       discount -= i
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a solution to the question

```
for i in my_list:
    while discount> 0:
        x = max(0,i-discount)
        discount = (abs(min(0,i-discount)))
        new_list.append(x)
        break
    else:
        new_list.append(i)
```